# Need to run a Jenkins job that was triggered after verifying the issue status on Jira

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jira

I'm trying to run a Jenkins job after I verify if the status of an Jira issue is 'Resolved' or 'Verify'. I do not want Jira to automatically trigger the job once the status is changed. I have tried using the Jira and Jira-ext plugin for Jenkins but this doesn't solve my problem. I also tried using the Conditional Step and for the job which doesn't really solve the problem. I can use the REST API's to get the status of the issue but verifying the value of the json returned and then running the job is where I'm facing the problem.

Comment: If you can already gather the information you need from the Jira REST API, it would be easy to make this decision in a pipeline. Have to considered switching this job to a pipeline job?

Comment: Yes, this seems to solve me problem. Thanks Rob!